# Will calcium supplements affect my strength gain?

Tags: strength, supplements, calcium

I've just started taking calcium supplements, 1 tablet each day with each tablet containing 650mg of calcium.

This is to try and negate the effects soda can have on on making it hard for bones to absorb calcium. Also because I realize there was almost no calcium in my diet.

This is just as I have started exercising with dumbbells each day to try and gain more strength.

Will taking a supplement of something I was deficient in, in this case calcium, have any noticeable influence on my exercise results? Will I notice any effect that would be attributed to eliminating a deficiency suddenly?

Comment: I'm afraid your question is off-topic according to the scope defined in the [faq]. If there is a connection to exercise, it would be great if you could edit your question accordingly otherwise I'm afraid I'm going to have to close it as off-topic.

Comment: @MattChan I hope the question is better now. If not, please feel free to remove it entirely. Thanks.

Comment: I'm also interested, and also named Matt. I think the question should be more like " Will calcium supplements affect a person's strength gains? " +"in a measurable way" or something to that effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't notice it immediately.  However, if you have a higher protein diet, the extra calcium will help your body digest that protein better.  One of the side effects of higher protein content in your meals is that your body can start leeching calcium from your bones.  Don't go above the recommended dosages though.

Comment: I've not heard that the calcium assists protein uptake before. Do you have a source for that? A quick search gives more studies regarding bone density and such.

Comment: Yep, I'd be interested in a reference to the above as well!